# Sort order of search results in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have following data available in PostgreSQL in same sequence-

```
Building Maintenance - Painting
Paint Expense
Painting Supplies
```

Search result should display in following order:

1. Exact matches should display first
2. Partial matches from the beginning of the text string
3. Partial matches anywhere in the text string**

If user enters search string "**paint**"
Result should be like -

```
Paint Expense
Painting Supplies
Building Maintenance - Painting
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your intended table structure? What language are you using? How should results be displayed (web page/app/whatever)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @dhke I am using PHP for this. Table structure is simple like id, account_number and account_name fields. I have auto complete searchbox when I type "paint" it should list above 3 items stored in account_name field.

Comment: Hi, this question isn't a great fit for the site, because it doesn't lay out a particular problem that you have with your code, and that someone else might have with theirs. Instead, it reads like a request for somebody to write some code for you; it would work as a job spec on a freelancing site, but you're expecting somebody to give it to you for free.

Answer (score 0):

This is for `SQL Server` but you will simply change this to `PostrgeSQL`:

```
DECLARE @f VARCHAR(MAX) = 'paint'

DECLARE @t TABLE ( v VARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'Building Maintenance - Painting' ),
        ( 'Paint Expense' ),
        ( 'Painting Supplies' )


SELECT  * ,
        CASE WHEN ( v LIKE @f + ' %'
                    OR v LIKE '% ' + @f
                    OR v LIKE '% ' + @f + ' %'
                  ) THEN 1
             WHEN v LIKE @f + '%' THEN 2
             WHEN v LIKE '%' + @f + '%' THEN 3
             ELSE 4
        END AS ordering
FROM    @t
ORDER BY ordering
```

Output:

```
v                                 ordering
Paint Expense                     1
Painting Supplies                 2
Building Maintenance - Painting   3
```

The first is exact match like `'paint ...'` or `'... paint'` or `'... paint ...'`.

The second: `'paint...'`.

The third: `'...paint...'`.

You can also do this directly in `order` clause:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ( v LIKE @f + ' %'
                     OR v LIKE '% ' + @f
                     OR v LIKE '% ' + @f + ' %'
                   ) THEN 1
              WHEN v LIKE @f + '%' THEN 2
              WHEN v LIKE '%' + @f + '%' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
         END
```

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try :)